# Is selenium only available in IntelliJ on the Ultimate version

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'am trying to make a web bot with Python in IntelliJ, i found a plugin called selenium that makes life a lot better. the only thing is that you can only download the selenium plugin with the IntelliJ Ultimate version. Does anybody know how to use the selenium plugin with the IntelliJ community edition.

Comment: This will help you [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selenium.html#selenoid-cross-browser-testing]

Comment: That is for the IntelliJ Ultimate version

Answer (score 1):

For coding with Python they have `PyCharm`. `IntelliJ` is designed for other languages like Java

Comment: I have a plugin installed called PyCharm so i can program in Python in IntelliJ, you recommend something else?

Comment: I definitely recommend you to use PyCharm for programming with Python

Comment: I downloaded the PyCharm IDE and the Selenium plugin can only b downloaded on the paid version

Comment: Currently i have installed Selenium with the terminal. If i try to run a run a code with selenium to open and close Firefox or Chrome in PyCharm is say "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' ". and if i try to run the same project from the Terminal it give me a lot of fault codes. (this is the first one that pops up " <stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
Traceback (most recent call last): ". i dont know what im doing wrong so i thought it was because i use the CE version.

Answer (score -1):

Currently i installed Selenium and its working. First i installed Pycharm and installed selenium in the terminal of pycharm by typing "pip install selenium", and after that i installed PyPI source archive by typing "python3 setup.py install". Then i needed the right webdriver voor my Google Chrome.

Its running perfectly.